# Getting HttpProtocolException in every 4minutes of idle time when using GRPC in client

Tags: .net, http, grpc

I'm developing client side .NET mobile project using GRPC. I'm new to using GRPC so im a bit lost...

The problem is.. when client is connected to server with GRPC stream and the connection is idle for 4minutes, this HttpProtocolException([exception image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaaGR.png)) happens. It seems like HTTP/2 disconnects the stream when it's in idle state.

I tried to use KeepAlivePing but still exception happened.
When i did some googling, it seemed like Azure load balancer and Azure VM's default wait time to disconnect when idle is 4min but our team uses neither of those services at the moment.

```
private static void RegisterGrpc(IServiceCollection services, Uri newServerAddress)
{
    services
        .AddSingleton(provider =>
        {
            var options = new GrpcChannelOptions
            {
                HttpHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler
                {
                    SslOptions = new System.Net.Security.SslClientAuthenticationOptions
                    {
                        RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = (_, _, _, _) => true,
                    },
                    PooledConnectionIdleTimeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan,
                    KeepAlivePingDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60),
                    KeepAlivePingTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                }
            };
            return GrpcChannel.ForAddress(newServerAddress, options);
        })
```

The best solution is to keep the connection alive.
How can i prevent this Exception from happening?
Thank you in advance.